# change LAN proxy

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, visual-c++, bho

I want to enable proxy from BHO for only Internet Explorer or if that is not possible at least set proxy for LAN.
After the below code is executed nothing happen, proxy is not changed and not enabled.
I want to change proxy settings when a user visit a website, and Idealy will be if it is possible to enable proxy only for internet explorer, so other programs can work normaly with direct connection which not need proxy, so if it is possible to set proxy only for internet explorer please tell me how, I would like also to use PAC automation script if it is possible.

This code have no errors, but proxy is not enabled, and nothing happen:

```
INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST conn_options;    
    BOOL    bReturn;    
    DWORD   dwBufferSize = sizeof(conn_options);           

    conn_options.dwSize = dwBufferSize;    
    conn_options.pszConnection = NULL;//connNameStr;//NULL == LAN   
    conn_options.dwOptionCount = 3;    
    conn_options.pOptions = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[3];   

     if(!conn_options.pOptions) ::MessageBox(NULL,_T("option error"),_T("option error"),MB_ICONSTOP);      

    conn_options.pOptions[0].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;    
    conn_options.pOptions[0].Value.dwValue = PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT|PROXY_TYPE_PROXY;   
    conn_options.pOptions[1].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;    
    conn_options.pOptions[1].Value.pszValue = TEXT("100.200.100.200:1020");    
    conn_options.pOptions[2].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS;    
    conn_options.pOptions[2].Value.pszValue = _T("local");     
    bReturn = InternetSetOption(NULL,INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, &conn_options, dwBufferSize);

delete [] conn_options.pOptions;   
bReturn = InternetSetOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, NULL, 0);    
bReturn = InternetSetOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH , NULL, 0);
```

The above code is supposed to change the proxy, but if I use it in the below code in the document complete event, it compile successful but will not change the proxy.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <exdisp.h>
#include <exdispid.h>
#include <mshtml.h>
#include <mshtmdid.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>

HINSTANCE hInstance;
LONG gref=0;
const CLSID BhoCLSID = {0xC9C42510,0x9B41,0x42c1,0x9D,0xCD,0x72,0x82,0xA2,0xD0,0x7C,0x61};
#define BhoCLSIDs  _T("{C9C42510-9B41-42c1-9DCD-7282A2D07C61}")



class BHO : public IObjectWithSite, public IDispatch 
{ long ref;
  IWebBrowser2* webBrowser;
  IHTMLDocument* doc; IHTMLDocument2 *doc2;
  IHTMLWindow2 *win2;
public:
  // IUnknown...
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv) {if (riid==IID_IUnknown) *ppv=static_cast<BHO*>(this); else if (riid==IID_IObjectWithSite) *ppv=static_cast<IObjectWithSite*>(this); else if (riid==IID_IDispatch) *ppv=static_cast<IDispatch*>(this); else return E_NOINTERFACE; AddRef(); return S_OK;} 
  ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() {InterlockedIncrement(&gref); return InterlockedIncrement(&ref);}
  ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release() {int tmp=InterlockedDecrement(&ref); if (tmp==0) delete this; InterlockedDecrement(&gref); return tmp;}

  // IDispatch...
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoCount(unsigned int FAR* pctinfo) {*pctinfo=1; return NOERROR;}
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfo(unsigned int iTInfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo FAR* FAR*  ppTInfo) {return NOERROR;}
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetIDsOfNames(REFIID riid, OLECHAR FAR* FAR* rgszNames, unsigned int cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID FAR* rgDispId) {return NOERROR;}

  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS FAR* pDispParams, VARIANT FAR* pVarResult, EXCEPINFO FAR* pExcepInfo, unsigned int FAR* puArgErr)
  { 
    // DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE: This is the earliest point we can obtain the "document" interface
    if (dispIdMember==DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE)
    { if (!webBrowser) return E_FAIL; 
      IDispatch *idisp; webBrowser->get_Document(&idisp);
      if (idisp && !doc) idisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument, (void**)&doc);
      if (idisp && !doc2) idisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void**)&doc2);
      if (doc2 && !win2) doc2->get_parentWindow(&win2);
      IConnectionPointContainer *cpc=0; if (doc) doc->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void**) &cpc);
      IConnectionPoint* cp=0; if (cpc) cpc->FindConnectionPoint(DIID_HTMLDocumentEvents2, &cp);
      DWORD cookie; HRESULT hr; if (cp) hr=cp->Advise(static_cast<IDispatch*>(this), &cookie);
      if (cp) cp->Release(); if (cpc) cpc->Release(); if (idisp) idisp->Release();
      if (!doc || !doc2 || !win2 || hr!=S_OK) {release(); return E_FAIL;}
      return NOERROR;
    }

    if (dispIdMember==DISPID_HTMLDOCUMENTEVENTS_ONCLICK)
    { // This shows how to respond to simple events.
      MessageBox(0,_T("Try pressing some keys on the keyboard!"),_T("BHO"),MB_OK); 
      return NOERROR;
    }

    if (dispIdMember==DISPID_HTMLDOCUMENTEVENTS_ONKEYDOWN)
    { // This shows how to examine the "event object" of an event
      IDispatch *param1=0; if (pDispParams->cArgs==1 && (pDispParams->rgvarg)[0].vt==VT_DISPATCH) param1=(pDispParams->rgvarg)[0].pdispVal;
      IHTMLEventObj *pEvtObj=0; if (param1) param1->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLEventObj, (void**)&pEvtObj);
      long keycode; HRESULT hr; if (pEvtObj) hr=pEvtObj->get_keyCode(&keycode);
      if (pEvtObj) pEvtObj->Release();
      if (!pEvtObj || hr!=S_OK) return E_FAIL;
      // This shows how to manipulate the CSS style of an element
      int i=keycode-32; if (i<0) i=0; if (i>63) i=63; i*=4;
      wchar_t buf[100]; wsprintfW(buf,L"rgb(%i,%i,%i)",i,255-i,i/2);
      IHTMLElement *body=0; doc2->get_body(&body);
      IHTMLStyle *style=0; if (body) body->get_style(&style);
      VARIANT v; v.vt=VT_BSTR; v.bstrVal=buf;
      if (style) style->put_backgroundColor(v);
      if (style) style->Release(); if (body) body->Release();
      if (!body || !style) return E_FAIL;
      return NOERROR;
    }
    return NOERROR;
  }

  // IObjectWithSite...
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetSite(REFIID riid, void** ppvSite) {return E_NOINTERFACE;}
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetSite(IUnknown* iunk)
  { // This is called by IE to plug us into the current web window
    release();
    iunk->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&webBrowser);
    IConnectionPointContainer *cpc=0; iunk->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void**)&cpc);
    IConnectionPoint* cp=0; if (cpc) cpc->FindConnectionPoint(DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &cp);
    DWORD cookie; HRESULT hr; if (cp) hr=cp->Advise(static_cast<IDispatch*>(this), &cookie);
    if (!webBrowser || !cpc || !cp || hr!=S_OK) {if (cp) cp->Release(); if (cpc) cpc->Release(); release(); return E_FAIL;}
    return S_OK;
  }

  // BHO...
  BHO() : ref(0), webBrowser(0), doc(0), doc2(0), win2(0) {};
  ~BHO() {release();}
  void release() {if (webBrowser) webBrowser->Release(); webBrowser=0; if (doc) doc->Release(); doc=0; if (doc2) doc2->Release(); doc2=0; if (win2) win2->Release(); win2=0;}

};







class MyClassFactory : public IClassFactory
{ long ref;
  public:
  // IUnknown... (nb. this class is instantiated statically, which is why Release() doesn't delete it.)
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv) {if (riid==IID_IUnknown || riid==IID_IClassFactory) {*ppv=this; AddRef(); return S_OK;} else return E_NOINTERFACE;}
  ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() {InterlockedIncrement(&gref); return InterlockedIncrement(&ref);}
  ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release() {int tmp = InterlockedDecrement(&ref); InterlockedDecrement(&gref); return tmp;}
  // IClassFactory...
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE LockServer(BOOL b) {if (b) InterlockedIncrement(&gref); else InterlockedDecrement(&gref); return S_OK;}
  HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateInstance(LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter, REFIID riid, LPVOID *ppvObj) {*ppvObj = NULL; if (pUnkOuter) return CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION; BHO *bho=new BHO(); bho->AddRef(); HRESULT hr=bho->QueryInterface(riid, ppvObj); bho->Release(); return hr;}
  // MyClassFactory...
  MyClassFactory() : ref(0) {}
};


STDAPI DllGetClassObject(REFCLSID rclsid, REFIID riid, LPVOID *ppvOut)
{ static MyClassFactory factory; *ppvOut = NULL;
  if (rclsid==BhoCLSID) {return factory.QueryInterface(riid,ppvOut);}
  else return CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE;
}

STDAPI DllCanUnloadNow(void)
{ return (gref>0)?S_FALSE:S_OK;
}

STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
{ TCHAR fn[MAX_PATH]; GetModuleFileName(hInstance,fn,MAX_PATH);
  SHSetValue(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,_T("CLSID\\")BhoCLSIDs,_T(""),REG_SZ,_T("BHO"),4*sizeof(TCHAR));
  SHSetValue(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,_T("CLSID\\")BhoCLSIDs _T("\\InProcServer32"),_T(""),REG_SZ,fn,((int)_tcslen(fn)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR));
  SHSetValue(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,_T("CLSID\\")BhoCLSIDs _T("\\InProcServer32"),_T("ThreadingModel"),REG_SZ,_T("Apartment"),10*sizeof(TCHAR));
  SHSetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,_T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects\\")BhoCLSIDs,_T(""),REG_SZ,_T(""),sizeof(TCHAR));
  return S_OK;
}

STDAPI DllUnregisterServer()
{ SHDeleteKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,_T("CLSID\\") BhoCLSIDs);
  SHDeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,_T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects\\")BhoCLSIDs);
  return S_OK;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{ if (fdwReason==DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) hInstance=hinstDLL;
  return TRUE;
}
```

Full source code is available for download here:
http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/bho.html

Comment: You got an early preview on the pain and suffering you inflict on your user.  Proxies are a lousy random failure inducer and everybody hates them.  There are very few good ways to diagnose such failure.  If you can't even debug the problem on your own machine, imagine what you are doing to the user.  He doesn't stand a chance, every web page or forum that tells him how to resolve a proxy problem will not work.  *Never* do this.

Comment: Did you try to control if your extension module **is** loaded by simply opening a MessageBox ? Anyway, if what you want is simply use different proxies in IE depending on the web site, a PAC would do the job without any programmation (and later version dependenies).

Comment: @SergeBallesta The extension is loaded and working, it does almost of the task, but it cannot change proxy, no errors. it have no permission to change settings using **InternetSetOptions**, how a PAC would do the job, I know what is PAC, but for IE host and url variables do not have the full web address of the current page, and my extension is based on full web address parameters. and other problem with PAC is that browser will update proxy only after restart of the browser, but i need proxy to be updated very often.

Comment: What are the return value of your calls to `InternetSetOptions` ? But I am surprised you want to update proxy so often in IE. What goal are you trying to achieve ? Maybe there are other (simpler ?) solutions ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta the return is false. but it is executed without any effect, I use same code in other program and it change proxy very well.  I need to change often the proxy settings, because I want to provide the best proxies, because some proxy servers work good at a moment then at other moment it is to slow, and I just filter them and send only the best proxies.

Comment: If `InternetSetOptions` returns `FALSE` you should call `GetLastError()` to know the reason why. I suppose you have allready find this article in Microsoft KB [How to programmatically query and set proxy settings under Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/226473/en-us) - note they do test result value and show `GetLastError` if unsuccessful ...